# ERROR running auth:web:login: EACCES: permission denied, open <filename>

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

When trying to Auth a Dev Hub or other org to VS Code for salesforce/sfdx, I am getting the error:

ERROR running auth:web:login:  EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/eye.../.sfdx/test-e2idy...ycs@example.com.json'

So I am not able the auth the org. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS Finder, the file info showed that all users have "no access" (no read, no write, etc...) to this file... and the date on this file was from 6 months ago, so I finally ended up trying to delete the offending file... but I had to jump through hoops:

`rm -f test-e2idy...ycs@example.com.json` didn't work! in fact it said there was no such filename! so I went into MacOS Finder, and moved the file to trash.

Voila! Problem solved, org auth'ed.

I welcome your suggestions on what was going on.

Comment: Who owns this file, i.e. created it? Are the dots in the filename something you added as replacement or indeed present?

Comment: In case with my colleague sfdx had to be installed with sudo, then to solve the issue we ran sudo chmod -R 777 .sf and sudo chmod -R 777 .sf see the comment thread on this  issue https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/53